# How can I verify an iOS app buyer

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I want to offer a hardware freebie to buyers of my iOS app. This means I need them to provide their shipping address etc.

How can I verify that the person requesting the freebie is an actual buyer?

It seems to me that I can make the offer through the app but how do I know if the user isn't providing multiple names and addresses?

I could disable the offer once it is used but it would be restored if the user deletes the app and reinstalls it.

Any ideas or recommendations?
Much appreciated.

Comment: You can write to iOS keychain and disable the feature. User cant clear it even if they uninstall app.

Comment: What if the user installs the app on another device?  The keychain check won't work then

Comment: In that case ask use user's personal information such as phone number or email to validate it. If user has already purchased, mark that in your server(Remember to validate it by sending sms or verification link). That way, it will be always unique. I don't think anything more can be done since user can still fake those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SKPaymentTransaction` response, if the user purchased (transactionState is `Purchased`), you could send their UUID up to a server or CloudKit or your own server, and when they send the hardware request from their device you could include the UUID, and check against the cloud-stored value, and only send them hardware if (a) they bought and (b) you haven't sent them one yet.

Comment: Thank you (all) for the advice. 
I was trying to avoid UUID but I think this is the only option that will get the results I need. Thank you!